# Why I use "n=str.read(c))!=-1" in java ,the "read" can't be used?

Tags: java

this is what I write, and the" read "has been highlight to wrong.And I don't know why .I have this"import java.io.*;",but it still can't work.And I really want to know why.

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
    File targetFile=new File("写入.txt");
    char c[]=new char[100];
    try
    {
        Writer out=new FileWriter(targetFile,true);
        int n=-1;


        while((n=str.read(c))!=-1);
        {
            out.write(c, 0, n);

        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();



    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR"+e1);

    }

    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `str` is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you must define **str** first.

```
 BufferedReader str=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

to define **str**.

```
    BufferedReader str=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    File targetFile=new File("j.txt");
char c[]=new char[100];
try
{
    Writer out=new FileWriter(targetFile,true);
    int n=-1;


    while((n=str.read(c))!=-1);
    {
        out.write(c, 0, n);

    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();



}
catch(IOException e1)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR"+e1);

}
```

Comment: well, because  I have use this class extend another which I have already define "str"in, I didn't define it in this class again."String str=textInput.getText();"and"public class PoliceListen1  extends PoliceListen implements Actionlistener".After I added what you said in it, the mistake disappeared ,but it still can't do what I want to do

Comment: well, thank you .my teacher told me to add this" button1.addActionListener(new PoliceListen1());"

Comment: then it worked, thank you so much for your patient~~